# Adding data to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am a programmer using VS2012 Ultimate edition, Visual Basic.NET, and have a question about adding records to a database.

I see that there are two main ways to do this:
An SQL statement and DDA.

Here is a link that shows both ways to add records to a database:

http://www.vistadb.net/tutorials/insertrows-vb.aspx

My question is this:
Can both ways be used to add records to a database and if data is added one way, can the data be retrieved from the other way?

Comment: yes, since it is the same database

Comment: Should LINQ to SQL be mentioned as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are completely different. So using a Insert statement to add data to the MySQL server would work, and retrieving that information with DDA is definitely possible.